# Getting exception as, Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, spy

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
NotificationServiceImpl notificationService;
```

When i use like above, I am getting exception for a test as, Argument(s) are different! Wanted: But but while debugging control is going inside all methods and code coverage is happening.

```
@Mock
NotificationServiceImpl notificationService;
```

When i use like above, I am not getting any exception, but while debugging control is not going inside a few methods its impacting the code coverage.
Could any one suggest me the proper mocking here. So that code coverage will happen as well as no exception will come.
**Stack Trace**

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
cwAlarmService.raiseNotificationProcessingAlarm(
    "device_id_value",
    <any string>
);
-> at com.cisco.inventory.service.NotificationMonitorTest.test_run_Exception_CW_Alarm(NotificationMonitorTest.java:189)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
cwAlarmService.raiseNotificationProcessingAlarm(
    "1b8722ad-0b9b-3327-98fb-5016fcf919f5",
    "Exception"
);
-> at com.cisco.inventory.scheduler.NotificationMonitor$TriggerNotificationDataCollection.run(NotificationMonitor.java:100)

    at com.cisco.inventory.service.NotificationMonitorTest.test_run_Exception_CW_Alarm(NotificationMonitorTest.java:189)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

and this is the test

```
@Test
    public void test_run_Exception_CW_Alarm() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<DeviceDetails> deviceDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        DeviceDetails deviceDetails = new DeviceDetails();
        deviceDetails.setCollectionStatus(Constants.COMPLETED);
        deviceDetails.setType("abc");
        deviceDetails.setIP("10.58");
        deviceDetailsList.add(deviceDetails);
        Mockito.when(invenDao.getAllDeviceDetails()).thenReturn(deviceDetailsList);
        Mockito.when(invenDao.getDeviceDetails(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(deviceDetails);
        NotificationData notificationData = getNotificationData();
        notificationData.setNotificationProcessingStatus(Constants.INIT);           Mockito.when(invenDao.getValidNotificationToBeProcessed(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(notificationData);
        notificationData.setNotificationProcessingStatus(Constants.PROCESSING);
        notificationData.setIsAlarm(Boolean.TRUE);

        List<StringPair> list = populateModelPathStringPairs();
        StaticList.ModelPathMapData modelPathMapData = new StaticList.ModelPathMapData();
        modelPathMapData.setName(Constants.GET_QUERY_MAP_FOR_SVO);
        modelPathMapData.setModelPaths(list);
        StaticList staticList = new StaticList();
        staticList.setModelPathMap(modelPathMapData);
        Optional<StaticList> staticListOptional = Optional.of(staticList);

        Mockito.when(invenDao.findStaticListByID(Constants.SVO)).thenReturn(staticListOptional);
        Mockito.when(invenDao.saveNotificationProcessingStatus(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any())).thenReturn(notificationData);
        Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("Exception")).when(notificationService).checkAndHandleDeleteNotifications(notificationData);

        notificationMonitor.run();

        Mockito.verify(cwAlarmService, Mockito.timeout(1000)).raiseNotificationProcessingAlarm(eq(ConstantsTest.DEVICE_ID_VALUE), Mockito.anyString());
    }
```

Comment: What exception exactly are you getting? Attach at least part of the stack trace to your question along with the code related to the exception and the stack trace.

Comment: Updated the stack trace and related code.

Comment: Okay, but you've consumed the original exception and all information related to it is lost. We need the original error occurring in your code to be able to understand the problem better.

Comment: Actually 2 tests are failing , Now i posted the original exception and related code.

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you also share the tested code? It looks like a UUID was generated and either set for the device instance as ID or passed to the alarm service directly.

Comment: change to Mockito.verify(cwAlarmService, Mockito.timeout(1000)).raiseNotificationProcessingAlarm("1b8722ad-0b9b-3327-98fb-5016fcf919f5","Exception");

Comment: @ArunSai I tried as above no luck.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

While mocking the methods of a spied object use `doReturn(...).when(...)` instead of  `when(...).thenReturn(...)`

**Longer explanation**

Although in `Mockito` the mocks and spies looks similar, there are some important differences.

- `@Mock` stubs all the methods. The methods do nothing and return `null` by default.
- `@Spy` does not stub anything unless
  it is told to. It invokes the real methods of the spied object by default.

There is another important implementation difference:

- `when(obj.someMethod(...)).thenReturn(value)` - invokes the method `someMethod` and then stubs the method.
- `doReturn(value).when(obj).someMethod(...)` - does not invoke the method `someMethod` and stubs it right away.

These two approaches have similar effect while stubbing mocks. But in case of spies calling the real method of a real object can lead to unwanted side effects.

---

So when you are using `@Spy` with `when(...).thenReturn(...)` there are some hidden side effects, which in your particular case result in generating an actual `UUID` instead of returning the dummy value `"device_id_value"`.

This also explains why your unit test works properly while using `@Mock`.

Comment: The best answer so far, explaining really well the side effects of @Spy and doReturn/When. Thanks!